# what makes a python webscrape output unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

i'm playing around with BeautifulSoup scraping a table and its contents and i've noticed I get different outputs based on how I end it - if i print it outright I get an output that has no unicode notation.

```
html = urlopen('http://www.bcsfootball.org').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for row in soup('table', {'class':'mod-data'})[0].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    print tds[0].string, tds[1].string
```

gives:

```
1 Florida State
2 Auburn
3 Alabama
4 Michigan State
5 Stanford
```

and so on (*btw, is there an easy way like .head() or index to limit the # of row outputs?*)

but when I wrap the last line in parenthesis,

```
print (tds[0].string, tds[1].string)
```

or assign a variable to the line and then print the variable,

```
output = tds[0].string, tds[1].string
print output
```

i get the ouput in unicode:

```
(u'1', u'Florida State')
(u'2', u'Auburn')
(u'3', u'Alabama')
(u'4', u'Michigan State')
(u'5', u'Stanford')
```

what's going on here? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the difference between an object's `repr()` output vs. its `str()` output.  I also note you are using Python 2.X, where `print` is a keyword:

```
>>> s=u'M\xfcrk'
>>> print s        # Formatted for output display
Mürk
>>> print repr(s)  # Formatted to view type and content
u'M\xfcrk'
>>> s              # It is what you get by default at interactive prompt
u'M\xfcrk'
```

Note the `repr` version enables viewing non-printable characters in a string, or characters that possible cannot be represented on the current terminal.

When you use print with parentheses, Python 2.X thinks you are printing a `tuple`.  When displaying sequences such as lists and tuples, the `repr` version of strings is displayed by default:

```
>>> print (s)       # NOT a tuple, so seems to work
Mürk
>>> print (s,)      # A 1-tuple
(u'M\xfcrk',)
>>> print (s,1,2)   # A 3-tuple
(u'M\xfcrk', 1, 2)
>>> print s,1,2     # prints normally.
Mürk 1 2
```

Comment: oh yeah... i've seen those things before lol. thank you kind sir

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all your output are unicodes. Beautifulsoup by default converts into unicode according to its [doc](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup).

Also you are printing `tuple` object when you are using parenthesis and `output`. And t using just uncode when doing it directly.